# For a one-shot, how do I handle starting equipment above level 1?

Tags: dnd-5e, character-creation, equipment, one-shot

I'm looking to do a one-shot to try my hand at DM-ing. In addition to this, I'm also building the setting and objective by myself as well. I've decided for everyone to be level 5 and have built encounters around it, however I want to be more accurate to the equipment a level 5 group might acquire. I'm assuming they have the starting equipment from level 1, plus whatever types of items they can be reasonably expected to acquire in 4 levels. Obviously, characters with magic items will fair much better against monsters with certain resistances against non-magic items.

I want everyone to roll characters just before the session starts. How do I handle their starting equipment when they are above first level (specifically level 5)? Do I give them gold and let them buy directly from the PHB? How much then?

Comment: I've undeleted this because duplicates are *useful* (thank you for asking it!) since they make it easier to find the right answers by searching. See [Why are some questions marked as duplicate?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/duplicates): “often they are left as a signpost pointing people towards the canonical answer to that question.”

Comment: I suppose my question is slightly different in that I asked about how to handle it as a DM to players, rather than what their starting wealth is specifically (although that was one of my sub-questions). How can I make this question more distinct?

Comment: You'd have to explain how this problem is different and isn't solved by the answer there. Does DMG page 38 not solve your problem?

Comment: I suppose after knowing their starting equipment, I am curious how I might distribute "one uncommon magic item" effectively and quickly, seeing how the magic items span pages 150 through 214 in the DMG. I will edit the question to reflect that.

Comment: Yeah, that would be a distinct question. I'm not sure whether it will get reopened though — how to do that might be too much a matter of opinion. If you're having a hard time figuring out a fair process for choosing them, focusing on that might help avoid opinion-ness.

Comment: Also, if you're going to change the question that much, consider just posting a new question. It is easier to get a fresh question evaluated on its own merits than to have a closed question thoroughly re-evaluated after completely changing it.

Comment: Okay. Because of your first comment, I'll ask a NEW question and roll back this one to the proper edit.